# same google cloud function different execution times and latency

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I currently have 2 projects Develop and Sandbox(exact same settings and region) in Firebase:

I have cloud function #1 deployed to both(same settings i.e region ,memory, maximum instances).

However, i have noticed that execution times and latency for function #1 in the Develop project are significantly faster compared to the Sandbox project.

How exactly can i debug to understand the cause of this?

Please see the screenshots of 7-day metrics and 14-day latency trace of the Function #1  for the 2 projects:

### Function #1 7-day metrics(Develop)

[image: Function #1 7-day metrics(Develop)]

### Function #1 14-day Latency Trace(Develop)

[image: Function #1 14-day Latency Trace(Develop)]

---

---

---

### Function #1 7-day metrics(Sandbox)

[image: Function #1 7-day metrics(Sandbox)]

### Function #1 14-day Latency Trace(Sandbox)

[image: Function #1 14-day Latency Trace(Sandbox)]

Comment: Your functions are in the same region but probably not the same zone or even the same rack of servers. Since neither function exhibits a problem, I doubt there is anything to do or be done.

Comment: Are there any significant differences between the two environments other than what you described?

Comment: No. Same code base is deployed to develop and then gets deployed to sandbox.

Comment: In that case I aggree with what John mentioned, since you can't guarantee that the funtions won't be in the same server that will have variations in latency and I don't think there is anything to be done in this regard

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki as it's based on John Hanley's comments.

Your functions are in the same region but probably not the same zone or even the same rack of servers, because of that it's inevitable that they will have differences in latency.

Since neither function exhibits a problem, I doubt there is anything to do or be done in your case.